# VBA Solidworks, Round Up

Tags: vba, solidworks

I am trying to make a programme in vba to construct an axle in solidworks, this has to be done by entering the the forces it is exposed to in a userform. My formula works just fine, but I would like it to round up all the values to a whole number, because making a 35,65 mm diameter axle is just silly.

I know I can do use  "Round(Diameter, 0)" for this, but I don't want it to round down because this would make it weaker.

Short: How does one round up a number to a whole number in VBA?

For example: 7,3 => 8

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA's *True* is mathematically equal to -1 and *False* to 0 so this should do it for you.

```
Dim axl as double
axl = 36.5
axl = int(axl) - (int(axl) <> axl)
debug.print axl
```

That assume that in a physical world, an axle's diameter cannot have a negative dimension. IOW, that formula rounds *away from zero* when axl is positive but rounds *toward zero* when axl is negative.

One last caveat; use exactly as provided and do not change `Int(axl)` to `CInt(axl)`. `CInt` rounds the value to the nearest integer like `Round(axl, 0)` while `Int` strips off any decimal portion.